# Есть ли IDE для pl/sql (oracle кода) с поддержкой иерархии методов?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ide

У меня есть много **pl/sql** кода с хранимыми процедурами, такими что одна процедура вызывает другую. То есть, процедуры (они же методы, функции) находятся в иерархии, как в типичном си-подобном языке.

Есть ли такая IDE для pl/sql (оракловского кода), которая покажет все процедуры, которые вызывают данную процедуру и все процедуры, которые вызываются из данной процедуры? То есть, не знаете ли IDE c  неким аналогом функционала Intellij Idea (ctrl+alt+H) для оракловского кода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**DataGrip** не подходит - там почему-то нет функционала иерархии метода.

Comment: не знаю есть ли там такое. SQL developer ftom Oracle https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/

Answer (score 1):

В БД Оракл есть вьюха `all_dependencies`, которая содержит информацию о том, какая процедура какую использует.
Сами напишите запрос извлечения нужного вам из этой вьюхи.
Некоторые IDE (напр, Toad) умеют показывать инфу из этой вьюхи в удобном виде.

Comment: Не содержит информацию по процедурам. У меня `SELECT * from ALL_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE REFERENCED_TYPE = 'Procedure'` дало пустое множество. Хотя у меня процедур очень много в коде. Кроме того, даже если бы содержал - всё равно ответ не подходит. В Intellij IDEA видна иерархия: функция A вызывает B, та в свою очередь C, D, E и так далее.

Comment: Попробуй написать `'Procedure'` большими буквами